# using a returned object from asynchronous method

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to do the following, unfortunately to no avail: 
1. reading a spreadsheet and get it as a parsed object.
2. use the parsed object to look for a specific value in it. e.g an email.

The spreadsheet serves as a database and the motivation is to determine whether a given email exists there or not.

Apparently, I have misunderstood the use of asynchronous methods as I can't grasp how to return the.

The calling method:

```
helpers.read('the-spreadsheet-id', 'Sheet1!A:Z');
```

The reading method @ helpers/sheets.js:

```
    exports.read = (spreadsheetId, range) => {
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: oAuth2Client });

  return sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId,
    range,
  })
    .then(_.property('data.values'));
};
```

what should I do in order to get a json object or similarly parsed data object to keep on working with at the calling method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `helpers.read` return? Are you getting the write data object back? Where are you stuck specifically?

Comment: using debugger I did not seem to witness any returned object from helpers.read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the asynchronous step to work, you have to either declare you are returning a `Promise` or that the function is `async`. Async/await is actually using promises under the hood, but it's a cleaner syntax.

For the `Promise` version, you have to return the value you want with the `resolve` function, and throw the error with the `reject` function.

```
exports.read = (spreadsheetId, range) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: oAuth2Client });

        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId,
            range,
        })
        .then(data => {
            resolve(data.values);
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};
```

When you are using async/await, you can wrap the query in a try/catch and throw the error if it fails.

```
exports.read = async (spreadsheetId, range) => {
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: oAuth2Client });
    try {
        const data = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
            spreadsheetId,
            range,
        })
        return data.values;
    } catch(err) {
        throw err;
    }
};
```

I don't use underscore so I'm not sure what you were trying to return here. I assume that `data` is the result of the query and you were trying to pass out `values`?